# Thread.Sleep() causing problems with Process.Kill()

Tags: c#, process

I've added a line of code to sleep the thread for 3seconds.

If I uncomment either of the two lines of code that are highlighted I get a bug - I know it is connected with adding the sleep - but why?

I assume `myProcess` is a thread in itself - is it this thread which is sleeping?
What do I need to change so that IE stays open for 3 seconds and is then closed?

```
class MyProcess {


    public static void Main() {

        Process myProcess = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();

        try {

            ps.FileName = @"IExplore.exe";
            ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            myProcess.StartInfo = ps;
            myProcess.Start();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        //>>>>>>>>following throw an error
        //myProcess.Kill();
        //myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
        //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Here's the error I receive

> Cannot process request because the process has exited

[image]

Comment: With no sleep you get no error if you uncomment both lines?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? Open IE for 3 seconds and then close it? First thing to note: After killing a process you can no longer close its main window; the process basically does not exist anymore. Also note that IE is "special" because it maintains child processes. What happens if you test with "notepad.exe" instead?

Comment: `Cannot process request because the process has exited`

Comment: @0xA3 exactomondo - pretty simple I know but I'm mucking around with processes and threads to get an idea of the classes

Comment: @DanielKelley even better - added a screenprint

Comment: @whytheq Interestingly I can only reproduce this if I uncomment both lines. My machine is a bit slow so I ramped up the `Thread.Sleep` interval and it worked as you seem to want it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll receive an `InvalidOperationException` if the operation was not able to complete. In your code, you may receive the `InvalidOperationException` if the process has exited before calling `myProcess.Kill();` or `myProcess.CloseMainWindow();`.

You can't kill a process when it has already exited. To fix this, avoid closing the process while the thread being idle. You may catch the exception or check if the process has exited before executing the commands.

**Example**

```
class MyProcess
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Process myProcess = new Process(); //Initialize a new Process of name myProcess
        ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(); //Initialize a new ProcessStartInfo of name ps

        try
        {
            ps.FileName = @"IExplore.exe"; //Set the target file name to IExplore.exe
            ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal; //Set the window state when the process is started to Normal
            myProcess.StartInfo = ps; //Associate the properties to pass to myProcess.Start() from ps
            myProcess.Start(); //Start the process

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message); //Write the exception message
        }

        Thread.Sleep(3000); //Stop responding for 3 seconds

        if (myProcess.HasExited) //Continue if the process has exited
        {
            //The process has exited
            //Console.WriteLine("The process has exited");
        }
        else //Continue if the process has not exited
        {
            //myProcess.CloseMainWindow(); //Close the main Window
            myProcess.Kill(); //Terminate the process
        }

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit"); //Writes press [enter] to exit
        Console.Read(); //Waits for user input
    }
}
```

**NOTICE**: If you are running IE8, you may notice that Internet Explorer 8 has implemented a change, where multiple open browser windows or frames share the same session cookies across all open tabs and windows including new IE frame windows opened by the user.

You may run the process **IExplore.exe** with the argument **-nomerge** to run a new IE8 Window session and avoid merging the new process you create with the one created before (the default process created by IE8 which merges with other processes). Thus, having a new process which you can control from your application and not that created by IE8.

**Example**

```
Process myProcess = new Process(); //Initialize a new Process of name myProcess
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(); //Initialize a new ProcessStartInfo of name ps

try
{
    ps.FileName = @"IExplore.exe"; //Set the target file name to IExplore.exe
    ps.Arguments = "-nomerge";
    ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal; //Set the window state when the process is started to Normal
    myProcess.StartInfo = ps; //Associate the properties to pass to myProcess.Start() from ps
    myProcess.Start(); //Start the process
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message); //Write the exception message
}

Thread.Sleep(3000); //Stop responding for 3 seconds

if (myProcess.HasExited) //Continue if the process has exited
{
    //The process has exited
    //Console.WriteLine("The process has exited");
}
else //Continue if the process has not exited; evaluated if the process was not exited.
{
    myProcess.Kill(); //Terminate the process
}
```

Additionally, the process exit code will be equal to `-1` if the process of IE8 was terminated unexpectedly, `1` if it was terminated by the user and `0` if exited passing control to another instance.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: +1 Thanks for this solution but I still don't understand why `Thread.Sleep` is making `myProcess` exit?

Comment: @whytheq I think that it's only related to IExplore.exe as described in the notice above. Have you tried passing the `-nomerge` argument to the process? I believe that this case only depends on the process, not your application. Have a nice day :)

Comment: ...ok - so for some reason the application thinks that the process has exited when it hasn't; but for most other processes my code would be ok? I'll try it with notepad.

Comment: @whytheq The application does not think that the process has exited. Simply, [Internet Explorer 8 has a new feature which manages new Window frames and tabs through one process](http://i.stack.imgur.com/z2d1I.png) which I believe may be causing issues in your application. To avoid this, simply pass the argument `-nomerge` to `IExplore.exe`. Have a nice day :)

Comment: so should I adopt this approach `if (myProcess.HasExited) ` before killing _any_ process - or do I just need to research the behavior of whatever process I'm dealing with and adopt this approach if it acts strange like IE8 ?

Comment: @whytheq I believe it's better to check if the process has exited first before attempting to kill the process to avoid exceptions. Have a nice day :)